# Create and traverse tree combining unique values from dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, tree, traversal

I have a small dataframe (15 rows), and I need to generate a random sequence of unique values that are in these columns. These values are interconnected.

This is an example of the table:

[image]
Example:
Taking every unique value from Channel, I need to be able to make a sequence moving to the right. So far I hardcoded a dictionary and have a tree structure in it, and use random.choice() to select a random key and move deeper in dict.

But I have more tables like this and it would be great to have a tree structure and then choose a random path from the root to leaf. It can be few trees all starting at each value of Channel column.

But I am not very great in data structures, so I am seeking for a help what would be the best approach and where to look to implement a tree structure with random path.

Example: For Display there are Instagram, GDisplay and google UAC subchannels, then each of subchannel has a subpartner and then finally campaign id. One possible random path would be:

Display -> Instagram -> Instagram -> NA

But it can't be Search -> Instagram -> organic ->.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I admit I am not sure exactly what you mean in the question but let me suggest the following solution.

If I understand one thing correctly, you end-goal is to somehow convert your own tree structure that uses `dict` as an hash table to each node's leafs, and be able to generate random paths of that tree from it, uniformly distributed.

So I guess your code must have been look something like this:

```py
import random

tree_node1 = {'value':1,'childs':[]}
tree_node2 = {'value':2,'childs':[]}
tree_node3 = {'value':3,'childs':[tree_node1]}
tree_node4 = {'value':4,'childs':[tree_node1, tree_node2]}
tree_node = {'value': 5, 'childs': [tree_node3,tree_node4]}


def random_path_recursive(node, trace = None):
    if trace is None:
        trace = []
    trace.append(node['value'])
    num_childs = len(node['childs'])
    if num_childs == 0:
        return trace
    else:
        node = node['childs'][random.randint(0,num_childs-1)]
        return random_path_recursive(node,trace)


print(random_path_recursive(tree_node))
```

I didn't use any significant structures to keep it simple.

First, except the recursive function, there's nothing wrong about this approach. This can keep you tree structure in place and get the wanted result. However, if you'll need to do it a lot, it'll not be very fast without any threading and parallelism.

You can also convert the recursive function to a non-recursive one:

```py
def random_path_nonrecursive(node):
    trace = []
    while True:
        trace.append(node['value'])
        num_childs = len(node['childs'])

        if num_childs == 0:
            return trace

        node = node['childs'][random.randint(0, num_childs - 1)]

print(random_path_nonrecursive(tree_node))
```

Finally, if you convert it to a Pandas datafarme, it'll be even more easy to select a random row.

You can do it as

```py
def make_rows(node, rows=None, trace=None):
    rows = [] if rows is None else rows
    trace = [] if trace is None else trace

    trace.append(node['value'])
    num_childs = len(node['childs'])
    if num_childs == 0:
        rows.append(trace)
        return rows
    else:
        for subnode in node['childs']:
            make_rows(subnode,rows, list(trace))
    return rows

import pandas as pd

def convert_to_df(node, headers=None):
    return pd.DataFrame(make_rows(node), columns=headers)

df = convert_to_df(tree_node, ['level_1','level_2','level_3'])
print(df.iloc[random.randint(0, df.shape[0])])
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you have small dataframe then you may use `pandas` itself to do the job - to find all possible paths you are looking for:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Channel': list('abaabbcccaab'),
    'Partner': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 3],
    'SubPartner': [10, 20, 10, 20, 10, 20, 30, 30, 30, 10, 10, 10],
    'CampaignId': [100, 100, 100, 100, 200, 200, 300, 300, 400, 0, 0, 0]})

# groupby - get all unique combinations
# size - simple way to count number of every combination
# reset_index - multindex to columns
df = df.groupby(df.columns.tolist()).size().reset_index()

print(df)
```

Output:

```
  Channel  Partner  SubPartner  CampaignId  0
0       a        1          10           0  1
1       a        1          10         100  2
2       a        2          10           0  1
3       a        2          20         100  1
4       b        1          20         100  1
5       b        2          10         200  1
6       b        2          20         200  1
7       b        3          10           0  1
8       c        3          30         300  2
9       c        3          30         400  1
```

Every row is a path. The last column is amount of path occurencies like count(*) in sql.